# Is there a way to pass inputs to a script from another script in python 3

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.10

I have a script that I need to run in a loop, however this script uses the input() function to define variable and I cannot edit the Original Script. main takes the input values as parameters, but those input variables are global variables. I am running this in pycharm if that's relevant. How can I pass those inputs in my for loop rather than typing them each time?

```
import Original_Script
  for i in range (9):
     Original_Script.main(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

I have tried:

```
import Original_Script
   for i in range (9):
      Original_Script.input1 = i
      Original_Script.input2 = 22
      Original_Script.main(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

I am expecting to not need to type the input values without edits to the original script.

Comment: Can you share the code from `Original_Script`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really can't edit the other script at all and it's using `input()` to read input, you can use `unittest.mock.patch` (or any other monkey-patch, but it's conveniently there) to override `sys.stdin`, the stream that `input()` reads, with a `StringIO` stream pre-loaded with the number inputs your other script expects, separated by newlines.

```
from io import StringIO
from unittest.mock import patch


def main(arg1, arg2):
    arg3 = int(input("Enter number 1: "))
    arg4 = int(input("Enter number 2: "))
    return arg1 + arg2 + arg3 * arg4


for a, b in [(1, 2), (3, 4)]:
    for c, d in [(5, 6), (7, 8)]:
        with patch("sys.stdin", StringIO(f"{c}\n{d}\n")):
            print(a, b, c, d, "=", main(a, b))
```

This outputs

```
Enter number 1: Enter number 2: 1 2 5 6 = 33
Enter number 1: Enter number 2: 1 2 7 8 = 59
Enter number 1: Enter number 2: 3 4 5 6 = 37
Enter number 1: Enter number 2: 3 4 7 8 = 63
```

(and you could use `contextlib.redirect_stdout()` to quiesce `input()` prompts too).